# Optional parameter in method not compile-time constant error with Rectangle

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, optional-parameters

I have a method where I'd like to use a `Rectangle` optional parameter with default value of (1,1,1,1).

```
void Method(int i, int j = 1, Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1,1,1,1)) {} //error
```

How do I resolve this? (I'm using XNA, so it's a `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle`.)

Comment: The only valid default arguments for references types are `null` and string constant expressions (for `string` only of course)

Comment: Ok, I'll just use four ints then.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare This isn't a reference type...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't.  optional parameters must be compile time constants, and `new Rectangle(1,1,1,1)` isn't a compile time constant.

You could have two method overloads, one that doesn't have a rectangle:

```
void Method(int i, int j = 1) 
{
    Method(i, j, new Rectangle(1,1,1,1)) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found a better way:

```
void MyMethod(string someString, Rectangle rect = default(Rectangle))
{
    if (rect == default(Rectangle)) 
        rect = new Rectangle(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

There may only be one problem: when the default and passed values match, it will still be true for `== default(T)`. But one workaround is to pass `null` and check for that to set it to default value ot type.

Comment: Can you pass null as a struct Rectangle? I don't think you can :(

Comment: you just pass `default(Rectangle)` and obviously `default(Rectangle) == default(Rectangle)` @NickSotiros